# Parsing XML using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, xml, retrofit

I trying to get exchange rates from central bank. Unfortunately they don't have api, which can provide data in JSON. Only in XML. I'm using retrogit 2. I already created two classes, which describe xml, what I got from web site. But when I tried to get callback's response I got an 404 error code. Maybe my `@GET` method isn't correct? Please help me!

First XML fragment. it contains array of currencies on a date:

```
<ValCurs Date="14.01.2017" name="Foreign Currency Market">
    <Valute ID="R01010">
    <NumCode>036</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
    <Value>44,5156</Value>
    </Valute>
```

And here is my interface:

```
public interface CbClient {

    @GET("/XML_daily.asp")
    Call<ValuteOnDate> getValuteOnDate();
}
```

And Service generator class:...

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create());
    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

And here is MainActivity class:...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "TestRetrofitClien";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CbClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(CbClient.class);
    Call<ValuteOnDate> call = client.getValuteOnDate();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ValuteOnDate>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ValuteOnDate> call, Response<ValuteOnDate> response) {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        ValuteOnDate valuteOnDate = call.execute().body();
                        Log.i(TAG,"valuteOnDate: " + valuteOnDate);
                        ValuteOnDate valuteFromResponse = response.body();
                        Log.i(TAG,"valuteFromResponse: " + valuteFromResponse);
                }else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Retrofit Response: " + response.errorBody().string());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error message: " + response.raw().message());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Error code: " + String.valueOf(response.raw().code()));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("LOG", "Exeption: " + e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ValuteOnDate> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: can you post the error message? maybe remove the leading slash in @GET("/XML_daily.asp")

Comment: Yes. Already fixed it. That was a problem. If you post your comment as an answer - I'll accept it.

Comment: @Kroha can you post POJO of ValuteOnDate Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading slash in @GET("/XML_daily.asp")